# Qt seems to leak memory everywhere

Tags: windows, qt, memory, memory-leaks, settext

I have big problems with memory leaks in Qt.

The problems is that when i run methods like:

```
qwidget->show();
qwidget->hide();
qwidget->setVisible(...);
qlabel->setText(...);
qwidget->setEnabled(...);
```

then it leaks memory.
I do not create any objects on the fly. I have created all widgets on startup and I just hiding and showing widgets and changing text on some labels all the time.
And when I remove those methods, then it doesn't leaks memory at all.

Is there someone who know why it is that way or if someone knows what happens under the hood? Or does Qt have memory problems?

*I run windows 7 x64 with Qt 5.0.1 x64 in release mode.*

---

Now i have added a test code:

```
#include "qtmemoryleaktest.h"
#include "Content_Logs.h"

QWidget* m_placeholder;
bool m_toggle;

QtMemoryLeakTest::QtMemoryLeakTest(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    m_placeholder = new Content_Logs(this);

    this->layout()->addWidget( m_placeholder );

    connect( ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QtMemoryLeakTest::toggleClick );
}

void QtMemoryLeakTest::toggleClick()
{
    if( m_toggle = !m_toggle )
    {
        m_placeholder->show();
    }
    else
    {
        m_placeholder->hide();
    }
}
```

Memory grows everytime a click on the button. from 8 mb to 47 mb in  20 minutes. **But** if a replace Content_Logs to a QWidget, no memory leaks. So i Think there is a bug in Qts self gererated ui-classes? In Content_Logs i have  labels, lineEdits, Spacers, TableWidgets, Checkboxes, DateTimeEdits, ComboBoxes and so on.

Code in Conte_Logs:

```
#include "Content_Logs.h"

Content_Logs::Content_Logs( QWidget* parent = 0 )
    : QWidget( parent )
{
    ui.setupUi( this );
}

Content_Logs::~Content_Logs()
{

}
```

Comment: How do you detect memory leaks?

Comment: Both windows taskmanager and Visual Studios built in Crt memory detector. By clicking 5 clicks per seconds on a button that hide/show some widgets and sets some texts, it grows up 1,5 Mb per minute.

Comment: "and changing text on some labels *all the time*." Just how often is "all the time"?

Comment: SetText runs maybe 6 times each click. But that happens in my own method that is called onShwon() and it runs other suffs as well. But i removed that method and just run show() and hide() and see that those methods leaks most of all. And if i remove those. No memory leaks.

Comment: Could you post your testing code please?

Comment: I have now added some more helpful codes :)

Comment: This test code is nothing like what you implied in your original question.  Show us the `Content_Logs` code.

Comment: It runs show() and Hide() but not the others. This code is not the original because the original is much bigger and is not my private code. But now I have added the code in Content_Logs above.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that if QTableWidget is added in Content_Logs with Qt Designer, then it leaks memory when I call show() and hide() on the Content_Logs.